# Create an Activity Class Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-1.7

I am working on a project that needs to create an entry for every change done in the system and the changes done in the database, for example:

`Jane` update her profile profile `address` to `1st Street No.3`

I was thinking about using an abstract model that every Object reporting the activity inherits from but maybe the solution is to create another mechanism.

How should I implement this functionality and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [django-simple-history](https://github.com/treyhunner/django-simple-history) package. It stores Django model state on every changes done. Add `simple_history` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`. Then create an instance of `simple_history.models.HistoricalRecords` on each model to track history for all models.